# Deserializing private members

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I have the following code, taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/En-Us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#example-serialize-private-fields. It works fine to serialize the fields of Brains.Brain, but when deserializing, the instance created has (a, b, c, d) = (2, 0, 4, 4) when it should be (2, 3, 4, 7). I've tried finding more on how to use a Json constructor, but haven't been able to find much.

Would someone be able to direct me to if it is on the microsoft documentation (although I haven't found it); somewhere else where it is documented; or some example code on how I should be using it or something else which solves this problem.

````
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
//
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace BinaryFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Brains.Brain b = new(3);
            Type btype = typeof(Brains).GetNestedTypes().Where(brain => (brain.GetInterface("IBrain") != null)).ToArray()[0];
            Loader.Save("test", b, btype);
            b.test();

            IBrain newB = Loader.Load("test", btype);
            newB.test();

        }
    }

    internal interface IBrain
    {
        public void test();
    }
    class Brains {
        [JsonIncludePrivateFields]
        public class Brain : IBrain 
        {
            private int a = 2;
            private int b;
            public int c = 4;
            public int d;

            /*
            [JsonConstructor]
            public Brain(int a, int b, int c, int d) =>
            (this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d) = (a, b, c, d);
            */

            public Brain(int B)
            {
                this.b = B;
                this.d = B + 4;
            }
            public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {c} {d}");
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
    public class JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute : Attribute { }

    internal static class Loader
    {
        static void AddPrivateFieldsModifier(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
        {
            if (jsonTypeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;

            if (!jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute), inherit: false))
                return;

            foreach (FieldInfo field in jsonTypeInfo.Type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo = jsonTypeInfo.CreateJsonPropertyInfo(field.FieldType, field.Name);
                jsonPropertyInfo.Get = field.GetValue;
                jsonPropertyInfo.Set = field.SetValue;

                jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Add(jsonPropertyInfo);
            }
        }

        public static void Save(string fileName, IBrain brain, Type brainType)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IncludeFields = true,
                WriteIndented = true,
                TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
                {
                    Modifiers = { AddPrivateFieldsModifier }
                }
            };
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, brainType, options));
            File.WriteAllText(fileName + ".json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, options));
        }

        public static IBrain Load(string fileName, Type brainType)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IncludeFields = true,
                WriteIndented = true,
                TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
                {
                    Modifiers = { AddPrivateFieldsModifier }
                }
            };
            return (IBrain)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText(fileName + ".json"), brainType, options);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Don't rely on fields in the first place. All the docs show serializing and deserializing *properties*, not fields. Fields are just implementation details, free to change as the developer sees fit. Only properties are considered part of a class's surface. *All* serializers, whether it's for XML, JSON, Protocol Buffers or anything else, work with properties by default, not fields. Otherwise the smallest change would break the application

Comment: What are you trying to do? From this and previous questions it seems you're trying to hack JSON instead of working with the format. JSON has no types, no inheritance. If you want to store and retrieve polymorphic data you'll have to add extra data to the JSON text. You'll also have to work in a way supported by your serializer. If you *don't* want a discriminator field, you'll have to write a custom type converter.

Comment: I am trying to make a system where someone can just add their own untrained ML class/model to interact with a frontend. The reason I am trying to serialize the private members is so that it stores any trained fields that aren't made public but required for the ML model to work. Is there another way I should be doing this? - Like requiring the ML class to use public properties for the data someone wants to be stored? (would it be better to use a format other than json?)

Comment: Making a property public isn't usually a big deal. It doesn't mean the setter is public either. Also if the class has it's own "save" and "load" method then using internal make them public in your library but private to the outside and for serialization they are considered public and works perfectly

Comment: Why invent your own format instead of using a standard one like `onnx` ? This is supported by multiple libraries and systems, including [ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/save-load-machine-learning-models-ml-net#save-an-onnx-model-locally). There's [a lot of ready-made tooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-onnx-model) too, including [tools to convert other framework formats to ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/onnxmltools)

Comment: Using onnx would mean it handles stages of the ML training itself, the intent of my program is to build ML models from scratch. If I shouldn't use json, should I use binary files? In which case how would I go about saving an object to a binary file - BinaryWriter/BinaryReader in .NET only save primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I changed, but it works now for some reason?
Edit: It was adding brainType to the serializer.

````
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
//
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata;

namespace BinaryFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Brains.Brain b = new(3);
            Type btype = typeof(Brains).GetNestedTypes().Where(brain => (brain.GetInterface("IBrain") != null)).ToArray()[0];
            Loader.Save("test", b, btype);
            b.test();

            IBrain newB = Loader.Load("test", btype);
            newB.test();

        }
    }

    internal interface IBrain
    {
        public void test();
    }

    class Brains
    {
        [JsonIncludePrivateFields]
        public class Brain : IBrain
        {
            private int a = 2;
            private int b;
            public int c = 4;
            public int d;

            public Brain() // for use by deserializer
            {
                Console.WriteLine("called");
            }

            public Brain(int B)
            {
                this.b = B;
                this.d = B + 4;
                this.a = 1;
            }
            public void test()
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {c} {d}");
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct)]
    public class JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute : Attribute { }

    internal static class Loader
    {
        static void AddPrivateFieldsModifier(JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
        {
            if (jsonTypeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;

            if (!jsonTypeInfo.Type.IsDefined(typeof(JsonIncludePrivateFieldsAttribute), inherit: false))
                return;

            foreach (FieldInfo field in jsonTypeInfo.Type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                JsonPropertyInfo jsonPropertyInfo = jsonTypeInfo.CreateJsonPropertyInfo(field.FieldType, field.Name);
                jsonPropertyInfo.Get = field.GetValue;
                jsonPropertyInfo.Set = field.SetValue;

                jsonTypeInfo.Properties.Add(jsonPropertyInfo);
            }
        }

        public static void Save(string fileName, IBrain brain, Type brainType)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IncludeFields = true,
                WriteIndented = true,
                TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
                {
                    Modifiers = { AddPrivateFieldsModifier }
                }
            };
            
            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, brainType, options));
            //JsonSerializer.SerializeToDocument();
            File.WriteAllText(fileName + ".json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(brain, brainType, options));
        }

        public static IBrain Load(string fileName, Type brainType)
        {
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                IncludeFields = true,
                WriteIndented = true,
                TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
                {
                    Modifiers = { AddPrivateFieldsModifier }
                }
            };
            Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName + ".json"));
            return (IBrain)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText(fileName + ".json"), brainType, options);
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did wrong but I managed to make it work this (simple) way:

```
class Brains
{
    public class Brain : IBrain
    {
        [JsonInclude]
        private int a = 2;
        [JsonInclude]
        private int b;
        [JsonInclude]
        public int c = 4;
        [JsonInclude]
        public int d;

    
        [JsonConstructor]
        public Brain(int a, int b, int c, int d) =>
    (this.a, this.b, this.c, this.d) = (a, b, c, d);               


        public Brain(int B)
        {
            this.b = B;
            this.d = B + 4;
        }

        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {c} {d}");
        }
   }
}
```

and then:

```
Brains.Brain b = new Brains.Brain(3);           
b.test();
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(b);

var newB = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Brains.Brain>(serialized);
newB.test();
```

Comment: This would be fine, however there will be many fields being used in the final code - so I'm trying to reduce how much has to be added to the class. (I'm using the Type parameter as it is only known at runtime).

Comment: @Ioan why are you trying to serialize fields at all? They're implementation details that are free to change at any time. From this and previous questions it looks like you're trying to hack JSON for some reason, instead of trying to work with the format